# reading row names in read_csv2 (readr package)

Tags: r

I am trying to load an example dataset from here: http://www.agrocampus-ouest.fr/math/RforStat/decathlon.csv to run an example PCA.

The correctly loaded data frame can be replicated with this line of code:

```
decathlon = read.csv('http://www.agrocampus-ouest.fr/math/RforStat/decathlon.csv',
         header = TRUE, row.names = 1, check.names = FALSE,
         dec = '.', sep = ';')
```

However, I was wondering if this can be simulated with function(s) from readr package. Suitable function for this seems to be read_csv2, however, the row.names command is not available:

```
dplyrtlon = read_csv2('http://www.agrocampus-ouest.fr/math/RforStat/decathlon.csv',
       col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, skip = 0)
```

Any suggestion on how to do this within readr?

Comment: It seems you can't do it within `reader`: [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/README.html) they say "Row names are never set."

Comment: It’s spelled “readr”!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readr` returns tibbles instead of data frames. Tibbles are much faster and memory efficient than data frames but do not support row names.

Depending on what you want to do with your data after reading it in, you could either, add a column name to the first column (it looks like last names):

```
dplyrtlon <- read_csv2('http://www.agrocampus-ouest.fr/math/RforStat/decathlon.csv',
                       col_types = NULL, skip = 0)

names(dplyrtlon)[1] <- "last_name"
```

or you could convert the variable to a data frame, and use the content of the first column to set up row names:

```
r <- as.data.frame(dplyrtlon)
rownames(r) <- r[, 1]
r <- r[, -1]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I will try the tibble approach and see if I can work with tibbles in FactoMineR package.